# I need some help doing a regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm using netbeans and I want to wrap $this->escape(stuff) around specific stuff in more files, using the replace feature, but there's plenty of conditions, like:

match:

```
$this->$variable, $variable

$this->$array['something'], $this->$array[0], $array['something'], $array[0]
```

do not match:

```
$this->partial, $this->escape, $this->form
```

What I have so far that works ok

replace this

```
echo\s+(\$this->[->a-zA-Z_']+[^\s;(])
```

with this

```
echo \$this->escape\($1\)
```

It doesn't work with arrays and doesn't exclude anything, also doesn't match $variable

Could anyone help out, improve the expression so that it would reduce the torture of going through so many strings by hand? Any help is appreciated.

edit: just adding the exclusions to my working example would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what parts you're trying to match. If I understood you correctly then this should work:

```
(?:\$this->)?\$[^,\s-]*(?=[,\s])
```

If you meant to match something else, please let me know.

Comment: Well that didn't work at all. I'm trying to replace echo $array['something'] with echo $this->escape($array['something']) for e.g. and with the mentioned exclusions

Comment: See my edits. This regex matches all of the expressions between the commas in your answer. let me know if this is still not what you meant.

Comment: this definitely takes care of the ones in brackets, works just fine, but I need all the conditions, i need to do them all at once or at least make sure no unwanted changes appear if i do them subsequently

Comment: i need them to NOT match the words partial, escape and form when they come after "$this->", those are the cases I don't want to use escape on

Comment: Please explain. Can you provide an example to an expression that you'd like to match and that doesn't work or for an expression that this regex matches and should not?

Comment: This expression do NOT match the words partial, escape and form. It do not match anything after the '->' that does not start with a '$'

Comment: the expression in my question, doesn't exclude anything, but works (sort of) with the other conditions. I want it to exclude what comes after 'do not match:' in my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15339/discussion-between-davidrac-and-andrei-cristian-prodan)